# Prove combinatorics equality

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry

Prove the following:

$$ \binom{n}{0} - \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{4} - \binom{n}{6} + ... = 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\cos{\frac{n\pi}{4}} $$

All I know is that $ \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{4} + \binom{n}{6} + ... = 2^{n - 1} $, but I have no idea how to get the desired result from this.

Comment: I think the R.H.S. is $2^{n/2}\sin {\frac{n\pi}{4}}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

As the general term is $$\binom n{2r}(-1)^r=\binom n{2r}i^{2r}$$

Put $x=i,-i$ in $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr x^r$$ and add.

Again $$1\pm i=\sqrt2e^{\pm i\pi/4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose 2k}\pars{-1}^{k}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose 2k}\pars{-1}^{2k/2} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k/2}\,\,\,
{1 + \pars{-1}^{k} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
\half\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}\ic^{k} +
\half\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}\pars{-\ic}^{k} =
\half\pars{1 + \ic}^{n} + \half\pars{1 - \ic}^{n} =
\Re\pars{1 + \ic}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\pars{\bracks{2^{1/2}\expo{\pi\ic/4}}^{n}} =
\Re\pars{2^{n/2}\expo{n\pi\ic/4}} =
\color{#f00}{2^{n/2}\cos\pars{n\,{\pi \over 4}}}
\end{align}